# How to install gTile and other gnome extentions in Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 - cannot detect copy of GNOME on this system

Tags: 14.04, gnome, window-manager, ubuntu-gnome

I am trying to install gTile in Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 (https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/28/gtile/).

Instead of an on/off slider I have the following message at the top of the page:

> We cannot detect a running copy of GNOME on this system, so some
>   parts of the interface may be disabled. See our troubleshooting entry
>   for more information.

I read the "About" section and it specifies that the "GNOME Shell Integration" plugin must be installed in Firefox. I am using Firefox 35 and cannot find this plugin?

I am using GNOME version 3.10.4 and linux kernel 3.16.0-45.

How to install gTile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you are using Firefox and not Chrome. Chrome does not support the Gnome integration any longer.

In Firefox, go to Menu->Add-ons. In Add-ons Manager, click on Plugins.

If you see Gnome Shell Integration, click on the drop down next to it and select "Always Activate". This should correct the problem. Just refresh the extensions page and you should see the toggle switch.

If you do not have Gnome Shell Integrations plugin installed in Firefox, I think there are more complex steps to be followed to get the plugin installed on your system. There are a few threads out there in the past few months that I found. My OpenSuse 42x installation contained the plugin.